# Display a filter based on previously selected filter option

Tags: laravel, filter, html-table, laravel-filament

I have a table, where there is a user_id column, which will be referred to two tables, teachers and students. I have a flag column to identify the user_type. Based on the user_type, I'll fetch the user's data from the relevant table, Students or Teachers.

The table and form were customized and worked as expected. I need to add the same for the filters,  where the user can choose the user_type first and based on that I need to display the Select filter option with the relevant  usernames.

How we can achieve this in filament, is it possible to do that?

I have tried live, but it doesn't work with filters